# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Form LoadingElementId

Tags: ajax-forms

Can anyone please tell how do I reference the loading element id?

I guess I have to write an id of an html element such as a div or an img but I can't put a div or img invisible until it is necessary and I also can't even make it work.

I know I am far away from the answer. Please help!

Comment: Seems a little ambiguous.  Some code might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer a long time ago. I just need to set the div style to `visibility:hidden` and write its id and the loading item id in the Ajax form. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`visibility:hidden` has not worked for me.

The problem was solved by `display:none`