# LoadingElementId in Ajax.BeginForm not displaying the loading image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 app, and i need to add ajax loading image. I put this on my view

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
      "LogOn","Account",
      new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "div_loading" }))
```

This is my very simple div on the same view:

```
  <div id="div_loading" style="display:none;">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="" />
 </div>
```

When i click my submit button to post the form back, the loading.gif never appears. My code runs fine, but no loading indicator shows up. And the image is named correctly and in the right place. Does anyone have a clue why?

**Update**
Apparently, this has something to do with Telerik applications. If i create a regular MVC3 app, it works. When i create a Telerik MVC3 app, it doesnt work. Has anyone else encountered this with Telerik?

Comment: have you tried debugging it with firebug? Do you get any errors in your console?

Answer (score 14):

You could try this as well from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567488/mvc3-ajax-actionlink-and-delaying-loadingelementid-from-showing)

```
function AjaxBegin()
{
    $('#div_loading').show();

}
function AjaxComplete()
{
    $("#div_loading").hide();
}
function AjaxFailure(ajaxContext)
{
    var response = ajaxContext.responseText;
    alert("Error Code [" + ajaxContext.ErrorCode + "] " + response);
}


AjaxOptions:

OnFailure = "AjaxFailure";
OnBegin = "AjaxBegin";
OnComplete = "AjaxComplete";
```

Comment: I think the OnBegin might be the way to go, but its not calling my method AjaxBegin. I do it like so new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "return AjaxBegin()" })

Comment: AjaxOptions Events take either a javascript string or a javascript function name, so that should work as long as your AjaxBegin function is on the global namespace. Does it work if you go : new AjaxOptions { OnBegin ="AjaxBegin" }

Comment: @user1202717 Hey, just wanted to follow up and see if this worked out for you?

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous. That's what I have been after.

Comment: @BoundForGlory Hey, just wanted to follow up and see if this worked out for you?

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to shy away from attaching a loading iamge to every ajax call I make.

The top answer here is a solution to display an ajax spinner (loading image) whenever ajax makes a send call:

[Display spinner while waiting For ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733939/display-spinner-while-waiting-for-an-image-to-display-from-an-action/10734016#10734016)

It has the functionality you need. Just use javascript to attach the display of the image to the ajax calls.

It should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindSpinner();
        });

        function BindSpinner() {
            $("#div_loading").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
                $(this).show();
            }).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
                $(this).hide();
            }).bind("ajaxError", function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        };
    </script>
```

What this does is display the div on ajax send and hides it upon ajax stop or error for all calls on your page. If you place this script and the div in your _layout it will do this for every Ajax call on your site.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added this to my _Layout.cshtml and i still didnt see the loader. Is ajaxSend a method i need to create?

Comment: Seems obvious but is the image loaded into your project? Try setting the alternate text to something to make sure the div is displayed. Oh and make sure your div is in the _layout too.

Comment: Yes, its there. If i remove the style="display:none" and refresh, the gif shows up. Trust me, i looked at that first.

Comment: Try setting the z-index on the div maybe the image is not loading in front. style='z-index:1234';

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this instead. I got it from the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440151/asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-loadingelementid)

```
<div id="div_loading" style="visibility:hidden;">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that with my fingers crossed, it didnt work :( I setup a sample project, and it works. I move it to my main project and it doesnt. But this seems so simple. Ive hid and displayed objects before

Comment: any chance your loading gif isn't being copied to your output directory? Is the Build Action set to Content and Copy To Output set to Copy Always/Copy If Newer?

Comment: I think display:none is correct. I tried both and the way is used in question worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it changing the name of the element to be hidden/shown. I used camel-case format: "myDivToBeHidden"

The element needs the "display" property set to "none".